# How to upload image in a custom S3 Bucket ionic-angular 3.9.2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-s3, storage

```
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';
import to from '../../../../providers/providers';

async uploadAvatar() {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Uploading image...'
    });
    loading.present();
    let toUpload: { img?: string, key?: any } = {}
    toUpload.img = "image-association.jpeg";
    toUpload.key = this.images[0].data;
    //Remove previous pic
    let [errR, dataR] = await to(Storage.remove("image-association", { level: 'private' }));
    console.log(errR, dataR)
    //Even if remove fails, add new profile pic to S3 storage
    let [errStore, dataStore] = await to(Storage.put(toUpload.img, toUpload.key, { level: 'protected', 
    contentType: 'image/*', }));
    if (errStore || !dataStore) {
        console.log('upload failed....', errStore);
        loading.dismiss();
        return;
    }
    loading.dismiss();
  }
```

Hello i'm trying to upload image on a S3 bucket I created.
The bucket name have this pattern : [ProjectName]-association-bucket-[ProjectID].
The problem is that with that code it store in the bucket with the folowing pattern : [ProjectName]-userfiles-mobilehub-[ProjectId].
How and where can i specify my own bucket name to store images in my bucket (the objectif is to store the image with a randomised name like a token at the root of the bucket).

Answer (score 1):

Finally i did this in lambda with the help of this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html